# Как поменять местами биты в байте на ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Необходимо поменять местами 7-ой разряд с 1-ым, 5-ый со 2-ым в заданном числе.
Помогите, пожалуйста, вообще идей нет, как это можно реализовать...

Answer (score 2):

Самый эффективный и практичный способ — создать таблицу, которая для каждого значения байта сразу даст готовый ответ. Возможно также генерация таблиц для каждого полубайта — это даст экономию по памяти.

Если делать вручную то общий алгоритм примерно таков:

- Выделить младший бит `and`'ом
- Переместить его `shl`/`shr`'ом в нужное место
- Установить в другом регистре/ячейке памяти `xor`/`or`'ом в нужное место
- Повторить

На x86 возможна более быстрый и простой алгоритм (спасибо @Mike'у за идею):

```
    mov cx, 8 ; счётчик битов, на i386+ использовать ecx
L:
    shl al, 1 ; выдвинуть старший необработанный бит в CF
    rcr bl, 1 ; задвинуть бит из CF в регистр результата
    loop L
              ; после цикла bl будет содержать результат
```

Comment: А зачем бит то выделять and ? shl/shr помещает выдвигаемый бит в CF и забирает вдвигаемый от туда же. буквально `mov cx,8; L: shl al,1; shr ah,1; loop L`

Comment: @Mike, мм... не подумал об этом... только `shr` вдвигает не CF, а нули... а вот с `rcr`'ом — идея жизнеспособна...

Comment: @Mike ответом оформишь или мне добавить?

Comment: @Mike, Это круто, мужик. Чувствуется старая школа, когда дрались за лишний бит.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Добавь к себе, пусть ответ цельным будет, таблицы они конечно быстры :)